# SVNKit , show list of files to commit

Tags: java, svn

I almost use SVNKit API.

I make my client and I can not find a way to show files that can commit. 
In some of the clients such as Tortoise, we have change dialog with a list of files that have been modified. And we can choose files for "commit".

How can I extract the names/path of these files?

Does API allow you to do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You may have a look at:

*SVNCommitClient.doCommit(File[], boolean, String, SVNProperties, String[], boolean, boolean, SVNDepth).*

It first collects committable files and directories with *doCollectCommitItems()*, returns the result in an *SVNCommitPacket* and then commits this packet by *doCommit()*. You may copy that code and customize *SVNCommitPacket*, especially use *SVNCommitPacket.setCommitItemSkipped()* to skip files.